# Release of Ctrl and Shift doesn't work properly with Caps Lock

Tags: autohotkey

I try to do a shortcut of Ctrl+f+j so that the Ctrl+j will make j a left arrow, and the combination of f will make it a Ctrl (d should work the same with shift), so Ctrl+f+j will be considered as Ctrl+Left Arrow.

I've succeeded in making it work, but after I release the keys, f and d stuck and I can not return to normal mode.

I have the following code:

```
CapsLock & j::
{
    Send, {blind}{Left}
    return
    f::Ctrl
    d::Shift
    return
}
CapsLock & l::
{
    Send, {blind}{Right}
    return
    f::Ctrl
    d::Shift
    return
}

CapsLock up::
{
    Send {Ctrl Up}
    Send {Shift Up}
    return
}
```

this works well until I release the l key because the d and f keys can not be used afterward. Any ideas why? I just can't use them regularly They keep function as Ctrl and Shift

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing- why do you have hotkeys inside of other hotkeys?

Comment: I've updated the question. Check the explanation at the beginning @Spyre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to separate the combinations. Turns out ahk does not support nested hotkeys, and doing that messes the releases of the keys. The following code solved my problem.

```
CapsLock & l::Send, {blind}{Right}
CapsLock & j::Send, {blind}{Left}

CapsLock & f::Ctrl
CapsLock & d::Shift
```